# iAd Banner Not Displaying (not showing on storyboards)

Tags: ios7, iad, ads

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

I'm trying to place iAd Banners in my iOS App with no success.
I stumbled across this method and tried it (didn't work in Simulator)
and I don't know if its enough (adding the didFailTo....) for ads to work. I couldn't get it to work so please help me!!!

EDIT: It tells me that there are no ads available and configuration incorrect.
It doesn't even display test ads :(

Comment: please show the full code!

Answer (score 0):

I use `bannerViewDidLoadAd` when a banner is load and so show this banner with an animation, also you need to implement `<ADBannerViewDelegate>` :

```
#pragma mark - ADBannerViewDelegate
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"banner loaded");

    // Display BannerView
    _iAdBannerView.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         _iAdBannerView.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
}
```

And I use `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` when the banner is unload (so here, you can add an animation to move your view for example) :

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Print error
    NSLog(@"error banner failed :\n%@", error);

    // Hide BannerView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         _iAdBannerView.alpha = 0.0f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _iAdBannerView.hidden = YES;
                     }];
}
```